# Understanding .map and Stringify with objects

Tags: javascript

I was trying different thing on JS to understand how they perform.

For my test I wanted to understand what happens if I do 
`JSON.stringify(something)` directly vs doing it with Map.

With **`JSON.stringify(something)`** directly

```js
var rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(rockets))
```

Where I am getting this in my console

```
[{"country":"Russia","launches":32},{"country":"US","launches":23},{"country":"China","launches":16},{"country":"Europe(ESA)","launches":7},{"country":"India","launches":4},{"country":"Japan","launches":3}]
```

**Vs with `Map`** I got this

```js
var rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

console.log(rockets.map(d => JSON.stringify(d)))
```

Where I am getting something like this

```
["{"country":"Russia","launches":32}", "{"country":"US","launches":23}", "{"country":"China","launches":16}", "{"country":"Europe(ESA)","launches":7}", "{"country":"India","launches":4}", "{"country":"Japan","launches":3}"]
```

Now, I was trying to comprehend both the code and `JSON.stringify(something)`does make sense but when I look at `Map` , I see a `"` being added after `[` which I am unable to understand from where does it come?

Also, The result from chrome console and stackoverflow comes out to be different, can someone also explain me why am I seeing `\` before `"` in stackoverflow result

example `[ "{\"country\":\"Russia\",\"launches\":32}",`

To summarise, my **Prime Question**  is how does .map work with json stringify?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don’t need the arg in the map, you can just pass the reference to `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `JSON.stringify(rockets)` results in a single long **string**, which contains serialized data that can be turned back into an array of objects with `JSON.parse`.

The second `rockets.map(d => JSON.stringify(d)` results in an **array**, each of whose items is a string that can be deserialized back into a small object.

The backslashes before the `"`s in the lower code are a bit confusing, they're because the stack console delimits strings with `"`. It would be clearer if it used `'` - with `'`s, the bottom result would look like

```
[
  '{"country": "Russia","launches": 32}',
  '{"country": "US","launches": 23}',
  '{"country": "China","launches": 16}',
  // ...
]
```

This is the *exact same array* that results from your second snippet

```js
var rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

console.log(rockets.map(d => JSON.stringify(d)))
```

except that it's displayed in a format that's easier to read, because the array items (strings) are delimited with `'`s, so the literal `"`s in the strings don't need to be escaped with a backslash first.

(just like a line

```
const str = 'foo'
```

is equivalent to using

```
const str = "foo"
```

, and how

```
const str2 = 'fo"o'
```

is equivalent to

```
const str2 = "fo\"o"
```

: that is, to denote the same character that you're using as the string's delimiter, you must put a backslash in front of it first)

Note that JSON strings require keys and string values to be surrounded with double quotes `"`, but object literals (such as displayed above) do not.

Comment: **The first JSON.stringify(rockets) results in a single long string** then shouldn't the result be like `"[
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
]"` and the `console.log(JSON.stringify(typeof rockets))` should say string (currently it says object)?

Comment: When `console.log`ging a string alone, the strings delimiters are not seen in the output - try `console.log('foo')` and you'll just see `foo`, not `'foo'` or `"foo"`. Stringifying an object does not change the original object - it only creates a *new* string that represents the object. Also, `typeof rockets` resolves to `object`, so `console.log(JSON.stringify(typeof rockets))` is equivalent to `console.log(JSON.stringify('object'))`. Instead, try `console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(rockets))` and you'll get `string`.

Comment: Git it. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to differentiate between `JSON.stringify(something)` and `.map(JSON.stringify)` is that the first one makes a string, and the second one makes a list of strings.

The `"` afer `[` in the result of using `.map` is because your console is trying to say that what you have in your `console.log` is a list of strings. Whereas in the result of `JSON.stringify(something)`, the entire output is a string so the entire output is prepended and appended by a `"`.

The difference between StackOverflow and Chrome's output, the `\`, is just is just an escape character.

Comment: if the entire output is string for `JSON.stringify(something)` then shouldn't the result be like `"[ { country:'Russia', launches:32 }, { country:'US', launches:23 }, { country:'China', launches:16 }, { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 }, { country:'India', launches:4 }, { country:'Japan', launches:3 } ]"` and the `console.log(JSON.stringify(typeof rockets))` should say string (currently it says object)?

Comment: Also, Arno thanks for answering and can you also please extend/explain you answer in stretch? still unable to understand it.

Comment: `console.log` omits the starting and ending `"` for string outputs! Try running
`console.log('foo')` then `console.log(['foo'])`